# Error while checking for service account using Lookup Function

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, k8s-serviceaccount

{{- if not (lookup "v1" "ServiceAccount" "{{.Release.Namespace}}" "{{ .Release.preinstall }}" ) }}
<< another service account >>
{{- end }}

While using lookup function for checking that if service account is already present it will not create another service account with same functionality as earlier they were created simultaneously but even after using the lookup function they are created simultaneously and if using the index function or providing the name as a variable $namespace:= {{.Release.Namespace}} and $service:= {{ .Release.preinstall"}}) } it is giving the error as nil pointer.

Can anyone please help with the use of lookup function and what is the error in using it

Comment: I'd probably avoid `lookup` here.  Unconditionally create a ServiceAccount specific to your application, or to a specific Deployment.  There's no particular harm in having multiple ServiceAccounts and the lifecycle issues around trying to share them can be tricky.

Comment: Thank you but if I dont want this service chart to be created simultaneously and should have dependency on the creation of other service chart then what should I do. For this I was using lookup function to check if the service account is present it will not create the other service account @DavidMaze